# Find Google page rank of a webste in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pagerank

I am using this function for getting page rank of a website . everytime it is returning -1 i.e. exception code . i am unable to find pr. I dont know what is going wrong and why i am not able to find the pr

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


class GetPR
{
    private const UInt32 myConst = 0xE6359A60;
    private static void _Hashing(ref UInt32 a, ref UInt32 b, ref UInt32 c)
    {
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 13;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 8;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 13;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 12;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 16;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 5;
        a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 3;
        b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 10;
        c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 15;
    }
    public static string PerfectHash(string theURL)
    {
       String url = string.Format("info:{0}", theURL);

        int length = url.Length;

        UInt32 a, b;
        UInt32 c = myConst;

        int k = 0;
        int len = length;

        a = b = 0x9E3779B9;

        while (len >= 12)
        {
            a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) +
                 (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
            b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4] + (url[k + 5] << 8) +
                 (url[k + 6] << 16) + (url[k + 7] << 24));
            c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] + (url[k + 9] << 8) +
                 (url[k + 10] << 16) + (url[k + 11] << 24));
            _Hashing(ref a, ref b, ref c);
            k += 12;
            len -= 12;
        }
        c += (UInt32)length;
        switch (len)
        {
            case 11:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 10] << 24);
                goto case 10;
            case 10:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 9] << 16);
                goto case 9;
            case 9:
                c += (UInt32)(url[k + 8] << 8);
                goto case 8;
            case 8:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 7] << 24);
                goto case 7;
            case 7:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 6] << 16);
                goto case 6;
            case 6:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 5] << 8);
                goto case 5;
            case 5:
                b += (UInt32)(url[k + 4]);
                goto case 4;
            case 4:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 3] << 24);
                goto case 3;
            case 3:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 2] << 16);
                goto case 2;
            case 2:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 1] << 8);
                goto case 1;
            case 1:
                a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        _Hashing(ref a, ref b, ref c);

        return string.Format("6{0}", c);
    }

    public  int MyPR(string myURL)
    {
        string strDomainHash = PerfectHash(myURL);
        string myRequestURL = string.Format("http://toolbarqueries.google.com/" +
               "search?client=navclient-auto&ch={0}&features=Rank&q=info:{1}",
               strDomainHash, myURL);

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myRequestURL);
            string myResponse = new StreamReader(
                   myRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            if (myResponse.Length == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return int.Parse(Regex.Match(myResponse,
                       "Rank_1:[0-9]:([0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }



}


public partial class PageRankChecker : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void checkpagerankbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String geturl= url.Text;

        GetPR a = new GetPR();

        int profmywebsite= a.MyPR(geturl);
        mypr1.Text = profmywebsite.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: i used this code   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20038/Request-Google-s-Page-rank-Programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void _Hashing(ref UInt32 a, ref UInt32 b, ref UInt32 c)
{
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 13;
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 8;
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 13;
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 12;
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 16;
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 5;
    a -= b; a -= c; a ^= c >> 3;
    b -= c; b -= a; b ^= a << 10;
    c -= a; c -= b; c ^= b >> 15;
}
```